# Laravel has many relationship complicated query

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have two models:

> posts

```
class posts extends Eloquent
{
 public $timestamps = false;
 protected $table = 'links';

 public function commented()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\comments','post_id')->where('reply',true);
 }
}
```

> comments

```
class comments extends Eloquent
{
 public $timestamps = false;
 protected $table = 'comments';
}
```

And data in tables is like that:

> post data

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("58837a559caf2fc968adc64d"),
  "post_title" :'xyz' 
 }
 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("58837a559c6as77777as"),
 "post_title" :'abc' 
 }
```

> comments data

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("58837a559caf2fa6a8s0v0z"),
  "post_id" :'58837a559caf2fc968adc64d' 
  "reply":true,
  "comment":'1st comment'
 }
 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("58837a55z7asd09zx865v9"),
 "post_id" :'58837a559c6as77777as',
 "reply":false,
 "comment":'comment'
 }
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("58837a559caf2fa6a8s0v0z"),
  "post_id" :'58837a559caf2fc968adc64d' 
  "reply":true,
  "comment":'2nd comment'
  }
```

Now I want to get all posts that contain count of comments (which reply=true) is greater than 0.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update of Alexey Mezenin's answer.

```
Post::has('commented')->whereHas('comments', function($query) {
    $query->where('reply', '=', true);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Post::has('commented')->get();
```

This will get all posts that have at least one `commented` relation.

Comment: thanks @Alexey Mezenin.
but  i want to get only that comments which reply is true..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Get all posts and then access every post to search for the once who have true as a reply:

```
$posts = Post::get()
$array = '';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
      if ($post->commented->reply == True) {
           $record = $post;
               $array[] = $record;
          }
}
return  $array;
```